# Why query with MAX(Date) dosen't return any record?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql query like below:

```
SELECT CPH.CheckPointID,
    CPH.ID AS Check_Point_History_ID,
    CLCP.SequenceNo AS Sequence,
    CP.Code AS Point_Code,
    CPV.ID,
    TT.Medium AS Description,
    [TEXT_TRANSLATION_ANS].[Medium] AS Value,
    CPH.Value_ AS Additional_Information,
    EMP.NAME AS Checked_By,
    CPH.AnsweredOn AS Checked_On
FROM CHECK_LIST_HISTORY CLH
LEFT JOIN CHECK_POINT_HISTORY CPH
    ON CLH.ID = CPH.CheckListHistoryID
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT CPH2.CheckPointID,
            MAX(CPH2.AnsweredOn) AS MaxDate
        FROM CHECK_LIST_HISTORY CLH2
        LEFT JOIN CHECK_POINT_HISTORY CPH2
            ON CLH2.ID = CPH2.CheckListHistoryID
        GROUP BY CPH2.CheckPointID
    ) tm
    ON CPH.CheckPointID = tm.CheckPointID
    AND CPH.AnsweredOn = tm.MaxDate
LEFT JOIN CHECK_POINT CP
    ON CPH.CheckPointID = CP.ID
LEFT JOIN CHECK_POINT_VALUE CPV
    ON CPH.CheckPointValueID = CPV.ID
LEFT JOIN TEXT_TRANSLATION TT
    ON CP.TextID = TT.TextID
    AND TT.LanguageID = LanguageID
LEFT JOIN CHECK_LIST_CHECK_POINT CLCP
    ON CP.ID = CLCP.CheckPointID
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE EMP
    ON CPH.EmployeeID = EMP.ID
LEFT JOIN [TEXT_TRANSLATION] [TEXT_TRANSLATION_ANS]
    ON CPV.AnswerTextID = [TEXT_TRANSLATION_ANS].[TextID]
    AND [TEXT_TRANSLATION_ANS].[LanguageID] = TT.LanguageID
LEFT JOIN [TEXT_TRANSLATION] [TEXT_TRANSLATION_RES]
    ON CPV.ResponseTextID = [TEXT_TRANSLATION_RES].[TextID]
    AND [TEXT_TRANSLATION_RES].[LanguageID] = TT.LanguageID
WHERE CLH.WipOrderNo = 304
    AND CLH.WipOrderType = 26
    AND CLCP.WorkCenter = 'WC03'
    AND CLCP.Facility = 'C1P1'
```

This query should return me two records with maximum date, but it returns nothing. I think the problem is in the INNER JOIN because when the line with the INNER JOIN is commented, the query returns the following table:

[image: table]

Comment: For fun and curiousity, change that INNER JOIN to a LEFT OUTER JOIN and stick TM.MaxDate into your SELECT clause. If you get records, but that TM.MaxDate field comes back NULL, then you will know for sure you are not getting what you want from that subquery.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. I have change the query as you said and every record in column MaxDate is NULL. What you suggest to change?

Comment: Are you getting back a CPH.ID in your main query?

Comment: I would check the results returned from the subquery in your INNER JOIN. See if there are Checkpoint ID's being returned by that query that match to checkpoint id's in your main query. Without knowing your data or schema, my assumption is that your WHERE statement in your main query gives you a set of Checkpoint ID's that is not listed in your subquery. That seems a little odd considering the nature of your data, but checking the subquery manually against the main query will help you understand where the mismatch is.